# Can't Connect "SSMS on Windows" With "SQLServer on Linux" Container On Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've pulled latest SQL Server docker image

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

Then started with port 1400.
(I'm not using default port 1434 because I've a local instance of SQLServer running outside of docker which my SSMS can quickly connect)

```
docker run  -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=pa$$word@123" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" --name "SQLServer" -p 1400:1400 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
```

This is my container info
[image]

When I check the logs everything looks normal. But when I try to connect from SSMS, I'm getting the following error.
[image]

What could be the reason? I'm also planning to build a .NET Core application to connect to this docker image but now I've concerns regarding if it's some TLS version mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to specify the instance name in SSMS in order to connect to it
[image]